# validate that checkbox is required for a textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a little problem, i'm searching, but i can't found what i need, i have 3 checkboxes and one textbox in a form, i need to validate that the user only can edit the text box if they alredy check one checkbox, and only can check one i try of this ways:

```
$("#tbCodCliente").validate({
                rules: {
                    checkbox: { 
                    required: 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked',
                    minlength: 1
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    checkbox: "Please check at least one."
                }
```

tbCodCliente is the textbox of the form

or try

```
('#tbCodCliente').change(function() {
                if( $("input:checked").length == 0 ) {
            //
                    $("#request-form").validate({
                        rules: {
                            checkbox: { 
                                required: 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked',
                                minlength: 1
                                }   
                        },
                        messages: {
                            checkbox: "Please check at least one."
                        }
                    });        
            //        
                }
            });
```

This is my checkboxes code

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("cbCodigo") %> <label class="inline" for="Codigo">Codigo</label>
<%= Html.CheckBox("cbNombreCliente") %> <label class="inline" for="NombreCliente">Nombre del cliente</label>
<%= Html.CheckBox("cbCiudad") %> <label class="inline" for="Ciudad">Ciudad</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disable the textbox by default and then enable it (and force only one checked checkbox at a time) in your change event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tbCodCliente input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
        if( $("input:checked").length == 0 ) {
           $("#request-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    checkbox: { 
                        required: 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked',
                        minlength: 1
                    }   
                },
                messages: {
                    checkbox: "Please check at least one."
                }
            }); 
        }
        else{
            $("input[type='text']:disabled").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("input:checked").not($(e.target)).removeAttr('checked');

        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/WZ59R/)

Comment: oh thanks!!, never think in that option, how i disable? addattr?

Comment: Add $("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", "disabled"); as the first line of ready event handler.